# Informal usage of the word "deliver"

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

I am accompanying some of my friend to somewhere and I want to talk about it with someone else. 
For example,

> "I delivered him/her to the airport."

But I'm not sure whether that's common in spoken english or not? If it's not, what would be an informal alternative for that in this specific context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kyle got it right. I'd like to throw in my two cents, though:

> Casual: I dropped him off at the airport.
>   Ironic: I transported him to the airport.
>   Friendly: I gave him a lift to the airport.
>   Irritable: The jerk insisted I chauffeur his ass to the airport.

Comment: Are the 'casual' and 'friendly' options really that different? I think they're both casual and both 'friendly'.

Comment: perfect! I love your answer :D

Comment: how would you suggest me to change the questions' name in order to be easier for others to find it?

Answer (score 2):

*Deliver* is normally used for objects. It can be used for people. However, in your case, I don't think you want to use *deliver*.

Definitions of *deliver* that deal with people:

> Formally hand over (someone).
>
> Surrender someone.
>
> Give birth to.

Not exactly definitions you want to use to describe your friend's trip to the airport.

Here are some better verb choices:

> I *took* him/her to the airport.
>
> I *drove* him/her to the airport.

([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/deliver))

Comment: thanks for your anwser. very informative and accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

Jesus delivered sinners from evil.  Mothers deliver babies into the world.  Aside from that, people don't generally *deliver* other people.  Well, they could, and you could, but it would sound rather more like you're serving your friend up on a silver platter than taking him to the airport.  Most people would simply say, "I *took* him to the airport."

Comment: thanks a lot. Those examples of deliver were very useful to me.